# remove a calendar from an overlay view

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible to remove a calendar from an overlay view. When I go to the "Calendars in View" page and uncheck the calendars that I do not want in the view, the calendars do not show in the overlay view but is there a way to permanently remove them from the list? Even though the calendars are unchecked, they still show up in the list of calendars in the view. I figure the list of calendars to display in the overlay is in some deeply buried XML file that I cannot get access too?

Answer (score 4):

**Steps to permanently remove calendar from overlay**

1. Open calendar overlays page
2. Click on the calendar link which you want to remove
3. In the bottom of the page you can see "Delete" button.
4. Clicking Delete will remove that calendar from the overlay

Answer (score 1):

Instead of unchecking the `Always show` box, use the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button.